# Drools-spring xsd Failed to read schema document

Tags: spring, maven, xsd, drools

We are trying to deploy a web application that doesn't have access to internet. There is an issue with accessing spring-drools.xsd.

Context xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:drools="http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring"           
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
                        http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring 
                        org/drools/container/spring/drools-spring-1.2.0.xsd">
```

POM:

```
<properties>
        <spring-version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <drools-version>5.6.0.Final</drools-version>
</properties>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${drools-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Warning:

```
WARN  o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader # Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'org/drools/container/spring/drools-spring-1.2.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) [na:na]
```

Anyway to fix this issue? Please advice

Thanks

Harish

Comment: That should be evident: Download the XSD and store it on your system and adjust the URLs.

Comment: Fixed it! Will post answer soon

Comment: hi Could you post what was the answer to this problem.